# Can a SAML2 Identity Provider delegate an authentication request to another Identity Provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, auth0

The case of delegating the username/password check to an external Identity Provider is known to me.

Now, let's imagine I have a Partner that has many customers. Each customer has SSO with that Partner. I want to use this Partner as my Identity Provider and have SSO with all of its customers.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

In my opinion, it's the best reason why small applications should use an organization like Salesforce as an Identity Provider. If they can authenticate to Salesforce, they can authenticate to you.